# Can jQuery add commas while user typing numbers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How would I go about dynamically adding commas as a user is entering numbers? Is there a good number formatter that would help? I have to add these numbers later so I eventually have to remove the commas down the line. But the screen needs to show the commas for better readability.

Comment: So wait you want a comma to be added after every number? So me typing 123456 would turn out to be 1,2,3,4,5,6? Or are you just replacing spaces with commas?

Comment: as macek answers, he most likely wants to add thousands separators.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Run the code snippet to see it work

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number">
```

Comment: You could just skip having to call jQuery again in the keyup function by just using this throughout. Then change var num = $this.val().replace() to this.value.replace(), and $this.val(num.replace()) to this.value = num.replace().

Comment: @Bob, I appreciate your input, but using jQuery's methods at the cost of calling `$()` is widely accepted within the jQuery community. That's *why* jQuery has the methods available in the first place.

Comment: I was just trying this chunk of code, and in Chrome and FF, it misplaces the commas by 1 place. For example, "1234" -> "1234" and "12345" -> "1,2345"

Comment: @maček  can you solve the problem in this code if i use backspace comma should be on exact position. jsfiddle.net/23Ccf

Comment: @Naveed (and everyone), it's been long overdue, but I've made updates to this code to make it a little more reliable. The regexp has been improved to address some issues too. This also allows a user to press backspace and have commas still be correct.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: doesn't work when the input is declared type = number :(

Comment: @maček Is there any way if this will work if `input type="number"`?

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra Were you able to make this work if `input type="number"`?

Comment: @maček how do I do this including decimal places?

Comment: It works only if I don't need to insert decimals.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an implementation of @maček's answer in vanilla JS if you don't want to use jQuery:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('input.number');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '')
                         .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
});
```

```html
<input class="number">
```

Comment: i can only enter 4 digit here , any specific reason , because i will have more then 4 digit, thanks

Comment: It works only if I don't need to insert decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
        function costt() {   
        var costs = document.getElementById('cost').value;   
            if(costs != '') {          
     //   alert("ok");     
                cost.value = cost.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
            } else {             
     //   alert("lol");     
                cost.value= 0;
            }        
        }
        </script>
```