# Perform a replace on a integer?

Tags: javascript

I promise that I've done my homework on this. It's a basic question, but I'm not terribly familiar with Jquery. Assume the following...

```
var cac = parseInt($("#currentAccess").val());
var acn = parseInt($("#addCapital").val());
var tn = (cac + acn);
```

How do I then take the variable tn, do a replace on it, and output it? This is an example that doesn't work...

```
$("#totalNeedG").append("<p>$" + tn.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + "</p>");
```

Thanks for this simple help!

Comment: re-tagged it to javascript as the question itself is not related to jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery

Answer (score 5):

`.replace()` is a String method. Not a Number method.

Convert it to a String.

```
var tn = ((cac + acn) + '');
```

Answer (score 3):

`String(yourNumber)` returns a string containing your number.
To convert it back, use `parseInt(yourString, 10)`.

---

And, as you are not doing it, ***ALWAYS*** use the second argument if `parseInt(str, base)`! If you don't, the base is determined automatically which is almost never what you want:

```
parseInt('010') == 8 // 0-prefix means octal
parseInt('0xff') == 255 // 0x-prefix means hex
```

While it's unlikely that somebody puts a number starting with `0x` in a field chances are high someone puts a leading zero for some reason.

Comment: Sheez! I thought I tried that already! I really need coffee. Thanks for the help.