# jQuery function to to format number with commas and decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using the following function to format numbers as the user types. It will insert a comma every 3 numbers. Ex: `45696.36` becomes `45,696.36`.

However, I've run into a problem with it. If the numbers after the decimal are longer than 3 digits, it starts adding commas to them. Ex: `1136.6696` becomes `1,136.6,696`.

This is my function:

```
$.fn.digits = function(){
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '') );
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
  }) 
}
```

How can I fix this so it stops placing commas after the decimal? I'm using jQuery 1.8. Thanks!

Comment: Way better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18676419/21838

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could accomplish this by splitting your string at the '`.`' character and then performing your comma-conversion on the first section only, as such:

```
function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var n= yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    //Combines the two sections
    return n.join(".");
}

ReplaceNumberWithCommas(1136.6696); //yields 1,136.6696
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/)**

Comment: dang that's a nice regex. Last time I solved this I ended up splitting the string _again_ to reverse it, insert commas into the array, and join again.

Comment: If using this with currency - which doesn't always have the decimals - adding yourNumber=yourNumber.toFixed(2) to the beginning sets it to always show the decimals even if they are 0

Comment: this didn't work for me "as the user types" unless i added yourNumber = yourNumber.replace(/,/g, ""); first

Comment: best one for a number with decimal

Comment: still nice and simple. and you can easily switch the commas and dots depending on what you need

Answer (score 2):

I use [accounting.js](https://github.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js) lib:

```
accounting.format(1136.6696, 4) // 1,136.6696
```

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but using the accounting lib really helped me. Thanks