# Add Comma After Every Three Digits in Input Value After OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, forms, events, input, onclick

I have a table/form that calculates monthly payments for a mortgage. When the calculate button is pressed, a JavaScript function will make a calculation based on the values of the inputs and set the value of that calculation inside of the `Monthly Payment` input. My problem is when the value is set for that input, the value gets displayed without commas. For instance, `1543` instead of `1,543`. If anyone knows anyway to add commas into the Monthly Payment input that would be great. Here is a picture of the Mortgage Calculator with the `Monthly Payment` input outlined:

[image]

Here is the code for the mortgage calculator:

```
<form action="POST" name="myform">
        <table border="1" bgcolor="#006666">
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" colspan="2"> 
              <script
           language="JavaScript"><!--
function CarLoanCalculator()
{
    form = document.myform
    LoanAmount= form.LoanAmount.value
    LoanAmount = LoanAmount.replace(/,/g, "");
    parseInt(LoanAmount);   
    DownPayment= "0"
    AnnualInterestRate = form.InterestRate.value/100
    Years= form.NumberOfYears.value
        MonthRate=AnnualInterestRate/12
    NumPayments=Years*12
    Prin=LoanAmount-DownPayment

    MonthPayment=Math.floor((Prin*MonthRate)/(1-Math.pow((1+MonthRate),(-1*NumPayments)))*100)/100
    commafy ("MonthPayment")
        form.NumberOfPayments.value=NumPayments
    form.MonthlyPayment.value=MonthPayment

}
        // --></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function format(input)
            {
                var nStr = input.value + '';
                nStr = nStr.replace( /\,/g, "");
                x = nStr.split( '.' );
                x1 = x[0];
                x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
                var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
                while ( rgx.test(x1) ) {
                    x1 = x1.replace( rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2' );
                }
                input.value = x1 + x2;
            }
        </script>

            <font color="#FFFFFF"
            size="2" face="arial narrow"><b>Mortgage Calculator</b> <br>
              Enter Your Details &amp; Click the Calculate Button</font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td> 
              <table border="0" cellpadding="2">
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"
                    size="2" face="arial narrow">Finance Amount $ </font></td>
                  <td><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"
                   face="arial narrow"> 
                    <input type="text"
                    size="10" name="LoanAmount" value="30,000"
                    onBlur="CarLoanCalculator()" onkeyup="format(this)" onChange="CarLoanCalculator()">
                    <br>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"
                    size="2" face="arial narrow">Annual Interest Rate </font></td>
                  <td><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"
                   face="arial narrow"> 
                    <input type="text"
                    size="3" name="InterestRate" value="7.0"
                   onBlur="CarLoanCalculator()" onChange="CarLoanCalculator()">
                    % <br>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"
                   size="2" face="arial narrow">Term of Mortgage</font></td>
                  <td><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"
                   face="arial narrow"> 
                    <input type="text"
                    size="3" name="NumberOfYears" value="4"
                    onBlur="CarLoanCalculator()" onChange="CarLoanCalculator()">
                    Years<br>
                    </font></td>
                  <td><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"
                    face="arial narrow"> 
                    <input type="button"
                    name="morgcal" value="Calculate"
                   language="JavaScript" onClick="CarLoanCalculator()">
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td colspan="3"><font color="#FFFFFF"></font></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td> 
              <table border="0" cellpadding="2">
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"
                    size="2" face="arial narrow"> Number of Payments </font></td>
                  <td><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"
                    face="arial narrow"> 
                    <input type="text"
                    size="7" name="NumberOfPayments">
                    <br>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"
                    size="2" face="arial narrow">Monthly Payment $ </font></td>
                  <td><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"
                    face="arial narrow"> 
                    <input type="text"
                   size="7" name="MonthlyPayment" id="test">
                    <br>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div align="center"></div>
      </form>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery function to to format number with commas and decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075014/jquery-function-to-to-format-number-with-commas-and-decimal)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784894/add-commas-or-spaces-to-group-every-three-digits?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct JavaScript code to add a comma after every three digits in the `Monthly Payments` input value for an onclick event would be:

```
<script
           language="JavaScript"><!--
function CarLoanCalculator()
{
    form = document.myform
    LoanAmount= form.LoanAmount.value
    LoanAmount = LoanAmount.replace(/,/g, "");
    parseInt(LoanAmount);   
    DownPayment= "0"
    AnnualInterestRate = form.InterestRate.value/100
    Years= form.NumberOfYears.value
        MonthRate=AnnualInterestRate/12
    NumPayments=Years*12
    Prin=LoanAmount-DownPayment

    function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
    MonthPayment=Math.floor((Prin*MonthRate)/(1-Math.pow((1+MonthRate),(-1*NumPayments)))*100)/100
    yourNumber = MonthPayment
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var components = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    components [0] = components [0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    //Combines the two sections
    return components.join(".");
    }
      //Seperates the components of the number
        form.NumberOfPayments.value=NumPayments
    form.MonthlyPayment.value=ReplaceNumberWithCommas()
    //Seperates the components of the number
}
        // --></script>
```

**Note:** the code is a bit out of order in terms of neatness and perhaps the comments, but the JavaScript syntax is correct.