# Javascript RegExp for matching different values with $ (dollar sign) as part of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm looking for a way to construct a RegExp object from a user input value that will match against some values which contains a dollar character $ (currency).

As I know this character must be escaped I have issues getting it to work correctly, especially in combination with other operators and characters.

I'm looking for to construct a RegExp that will work based on user input and hence it needs to be dynamic. Trying try to explain the scenario, something in this fashion:

User input: `"$50"` or `"50"`

```
"$50" // match
"$50 + $5" // match as it matches on "$50"
"$500 + $50" // match as it matches on "$50"
"$500" // should not match
"$5000" // should not match
"$5.50" // should not match
```

user input: `"$5000"` or `"5000"`

```
"$5000" // match
"$5,000" // match as it resembles the same value
"$5000 + $500" // match
"$5.000" // should not match
"$5000.50" // should not match
```

So basically it should only match the exact user input, with the exception of the dollar character ($), if there's a value that follows it but they are separated by a plus symbol (but still the same string), or if the value has a comma which is commonly used when writing larger numbers (for example 5,000).

Is this possible with a RegExp object?

Comment: Threw us a curveball with the second set of examples, where commas should be matched...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is it a lot easier and doable if not having to account for the case with the comma ($5,000)? If so, I think I can settle with not needing to match on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to prep the user input a bit — remove the `$` if present, and add the beginnings of our regex to allow an optional comma in appropriate thousands places. I've broken out the individual steps, though of course they could be combined:

```
var userInput = "$5000";
var userInputWithoutDollar = userInput.replace(/^\$/, "");
var userInputWithOptionalCommas = userInputWithoutDollar.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",?");
```

That last bit is a variation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075036/157247) for adding commas as thousands separators to a number.

Then, we build our regular expression, remembering that when we're building regular expressions with string literals, we have to double-escape (since backslashes are meaningful both in the string literal and at the regular expression level):

```
  var rex = new RegExp("(?:^|[^.,\\d])((?:\\$?)" + userInputWithOptionalCommas + ")(?=$|[^.,\\d])");
```

That says:

- Beginning of string or a character that isn't `.`, `,`, or a digit
- Find our number with optional commas
- And ensure it isn't followed by a `.`, `,`, or digit

The matched text is the first capture group.

Example w/tests:

```js
runTests("$5000", [
    {result: true, value: "$5000"}, // match
    {result: true, value: "$5,000"}, // match as it resembles the same value
    {result: true, value: "$5000 + $500"}, // match
    {result: true, value: "$500 + $5000"}, // match
    {result: false, value: "$5.000"}, // should not match
    {result: false, value: "$5000.50"} // should not match
]);
runTests("500", [
    {result: true, value: "$500"},
    {result: true, value: "$500"},
    {result: false, value: "$1,500"},
    {result: false, value: "1,500"}
]);

function runTests(userInput, tests) {
  var userInputWithoutDollar = userInput.replace(/^\$/, "");
  var userInputWithOptionalCommas = userInputWithoutDollar.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",?");
  var rex = new RegExp("(?:^|[^.,\\d])((?:\\$?)" + userInputWithOptionalCommas + ")(?=$|[^.,\\d])");
  tests.forEach(function(test) {
      var match = rex.exec(test.value);
      var result = !!match;
      console.log(
          (result == test.result ? "GOOD" : "ERROR") +
          " - Value '" + test.value + "' " +
          (result ? "Matches, got '" + match[1] + "'" : "Doesn't match")
      );
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to behave as needed. Using "$500" as input will match on "$5000", which is not desirable. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: @nikkop: I forgot to escape a backslash in one place (darned string literals). Fixed above. It had `+ "(?=$|[^.\d])"` where it wanted `+ "(?=$|[^.\\d])"`

Comment: Thanks, I changed into that and that part works as expected. However, when inputting for example "$500", it will also match on "$1,500", "$2,500" etc. Is this possible to fix as well? Sorry for not including this in my first post of non-desirable matches.

Comment: Removing `\\b` from `(?:^|^\\$|\\b|\\$)` seems to work, but I'm not sure if I miss out on anything else then or alter any behaviour. Is this the proper way to fix the issue? Thanks

Comment: @nikkop: Sorry about 500 matching $1,500. To handle that in JavaScript, sadly, we need to use a capture group as JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind. I've updated to show that.

Comment: for input = 5000, `(?:^|\b)\$?5,?000(?=\s|$)` have any problem? in other word, why should use `(?:^|[^.,\\d])(?:\\$?)` in the beginning and `(?=$|[^.,\\d])` at the end of pattern @nikkop

Answer (score -1):

## Version 1

Except the example with comma, the following Regex meets your requirement:

`(?:\$?)\$5000(?:$|\s.*)`

Remember to escape the `$` in `$5000`

#### Explanation

`(?:\$?)`: Match a single `$` sign if present, the `?` indicates occurrence of `$` to be 1 or 0.

`\$5000`: It is the input with `$` escaped.

`(?:$|\s.*)`: Matches either the end of a string or anything after a space.

---

## Version 2

Again, comma is not accommodated.

`(?:\$?)\$50(?:$|(?:\s(?:\+|\-)\s(?:\$?)(?:[0-9]+))+)`

#### Explanation

`(?:\$?)`: Match a single `$` sign if present, the `?` indicates occurrence of `$` to be 1 or 0.

`\$5000`: It is the input with `$` escaped.

`(?:$|(?:\s(?:\+|\-)\s(?:\$?)(?:[0-9]+))+)`: Matches either end of string or `+ $xxx` or `- $xxx` after the match, even if they are repeated.

Comment: That doesn't handle commas, and matches extra characters after what the OP said they wanted to match.

Comment: Added another version

Answer (score -1):

Converting $ to \$ and adding ,? to `userInput` value, makes regex pattern

```
var userInput = "500000000" ;
if(userInput.substring(0,1) != "$"){userInput = "$"+userInput ;}
var c = userInput.length-2;
for(var i = Math.floor(c/3)*3 ; i>0 ; i-=3){
  userInput = userInput.substring(0,userInput.length-i) + ",?" + userInput.substr(-i) ;
}
userInput = "(?:^|\\b)" + userInput.replace("$","\\\$\?") + "(?=\\s|$)" ;
```

for 5000, out put is:

```
\$?5,?000
//updated to
(?:^|\b)\$?5,?000(?=\s|$)
```

see [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lnh6DV/2)

**Updates done:**

- Changed `(?:..)` to `(?=..)` to stop matching after found number
- missed assign of replacing of "$" with "\$?" to userInput

Answer (score -2):

```js
 var regExp = /^\$(50*)|(\+50*)/igm ;
    console.log(regExp.test("$50")); //true
    console.log(regExp.test("$50000")); //true
    console.log(regExp.test("$50+50")); //true
    console.log(regExp.test("$50+500000")); //true
    console.log(regExp.test("$50.00")); //false
    console.log(regExp.test("$50.00+50")); //false
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to behave as expected as it doesn't return what you have commented it should return.