# Formating dollars with commas on Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to get a sum over a stacked column in a Highcharts chart to show both the $ and commas to separate thousands.

Here is an excerpt:

```
yAxis: {
   stackLabels: { 
       enabled: true,
             formatter: function() {
                   return 'Total: $' + this.total;
               },
       },
   labels: {
     format: '${value:,.0f}',
  },
  title: {
        text: 'Total $'
    },
},
```

The labels appear right, but can't quite get the "this.total" to display with commas for the value above the stacks. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should give you the commas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Highcharts.numberFormat` which has the definition like this

> numberFormat (Number number, [Number decimals], [String decimalPoint], [String thousandsSep])

```
formatter: function () {
  return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 1, '.', ',');
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ah7r2fy1/2/**

Comment: You FREAKIN' ROCK! That's perfect. Thank you!