# Adding Decimal Point

Tags: javascript

Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function(){

$('input.number')

  .on("blur", function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var num = $this.val().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");     

    $this.val(num);
});

});

  </script>
```

The output of that code is 10000 => 10,000

I want the output to be 10000 => 10,000.00

thanks..

Comment: var num = parseFloat($this.val()).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
parseFloat(num).toFixed(2)
```

Like:

```
$this.val(parseFloat(num).toFixed(2));//output 1000.00
```

For comma separator use this [SO ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12947816/2236219).

```
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
  }
var num = 10000;
console.log(commaSeparateNumber(parseFloat(num).toFixed(2)));// output 10,000.00
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vczv6nfz/)

Answer (score 2):

You could also [make use of `toLocaleString` with `minimumFractionDigits` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) of its `options` argument.

`numObj.toLocaleString([locales [, options]])`

***Example***:

```js
var number = 10000;
alert(number.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
```

*Note: Supported by all modern browsers, except Safari (it seems)*