# Adding separators to existing JS function

Tags: javascript

I'm terrible when it comes to JS. I have a small script that I am using in a Wordpress installation for a continually updating counter. Here is the code I am using:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
   var countStart = 147000000000;

   var count = countStart + (new Date().getTime() - new Date('12/16/2015').getTime())/.900;

   jQuery("#counter2").text(count.toFixed(0));
}, 1);
```

How can I amend this to output the number with thousands separators? I am  aware of the numerous threads on the topic of thousands separators, but cannot seem to make any suggestions work with what I have already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add commas to a number in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method:

```
jQuery("#counter2").text(count.toFixed(0).toLocaleString('en'));
```

It will add the thousands separator, as it is specified for the locale. English uses comma as the thousands separator, and dot for decimal mark.

For example this

```
var count = 102012.123;
console.log(count.toLocaleString('en'));
```

yields: `102,012.123`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
function formatNumber(){
  var a = 1234567890;
  console.log( Number(a.toFixed(0)).toLocaleString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was the answer that worked for me provided by a friend:

```
    window.setInterval(function () {
    var countStart = 147000000000;
    var myDate = new Date().getTime() - new Date('12/16/2015').getTime();
    var count = countStart + (myDate) / 0.900;
    var countSeparated = Number(count.toFixed(0)).toLocaleString();
  jQuery("#counter2").text(countSeparated);
}, 1);
```

For reasons beyond my abilities, the above two answers worked in a console but not in my script within Wordpress