# Jquery adding commas to numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox that contains numbers, everytime I add in digits it formats my number adding commas "onblur" event which works fine. But when I add in a digit when the number its already formatted the commas are not in the right place and at times adds in a zero.If I add in 1000000 its formats 1,000,000 but if I add or edit 1,000,0002 its end result is 1,000,0,002.

JQUERY

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

$("#mytextbox").blur(function(){
        this.value = addCommas(this.value.replace(',', ''));
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add commas to a number in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace(',', '')` only replaces first comma to to empty. You need a global comma replace. Try changing this line

```
this.value = addCommas(this.value.replace(',', ''));
```

To this:

```
this.value = addCommas(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).  You can turn your entire addCommas function into one line:

```
parseInt(nStr.replace(/\D/g, '')).toLocaleString();
```

Let me break down what's happening here.  First we're removing all non-digit characters from `nStr` by replacing them with `''`. This is a little more thorough than just stripping out commas.  Next, we're turning the string of digits into a Number using `parseInt()`.  This will allow us to use some built in formatting methods in the Number prototype. Finally, the Number prototype has a function [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) that returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the number.  The default is U.S. English, but you can optionally specify a different locale if you want.