# Adding commas to animated counting function

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've tried everything I can find online about this but they all seem to deal with static numbers, not animated numbers.

Is it possible to have commas added to my values as the number increases using this by modifying this function?

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
            countNum: countTo
        },

        {

        duration: 500,
        easing:'linear',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
              //alert('finished');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the commas wherever you're currently setting the element `text()`.

Comma code lifted from [add commas to a number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery)

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {
      duration: 5000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.floor(this.countNum)));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(this.countNum));
        //alert('finished');
      }
    }
  );

});

function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
  while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
    val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return val;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="counter" data-count="1000000"></span>
```

Comment: This code works better than many github counter projects and it is very lightweight. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `parseFloat` in case of string contain comma.
please check the below working code

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''))
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(getRupeesFormat(Math.ceil(now)));
        }
    });
});


function getRupeesFormat(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return val;
}
```