# Can Vue.js add commas while user typing numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

I see this [***topic***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632359/can-jquery-add-commas-while-user-typing-numbers), But this is Jquery, how can I change it to Vue.js ? Is `v-on` supported in Vue.js? Where is my mistake?

```
<div id="vue">
    <input v-model="amountModel" v-on:keyup="AddCammas()" value="{{price}}">
</div>

<script>
   el: #vue,
   methods:{
      AddCammas : funtion(){
          if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

          $(this).val(function(index, value) {
             this.message = this.amountModel
                .replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
           });
      } 
   }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need jQuery at all for this. You `watch` your variable, and in the watch function, compute the reformatted version, then set it back to your variable using `nextTick` (so it's not mutating before the watch is complete).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    price: 0
  },
  watch: {
    price: function(newValue) {
      const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      Vue.nextTick(() => this.price = result);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <input type="text" v-model="price" />{{price}}
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way if this will work if `input type="number"`?

Comment: It works with `type="number"`, but the input will be considered invalid.

Comment: how would this work on an object?  eg: `proposal.price`.

Comment: You can `watch` members of objects, @WhiteRau

Comment: @RoyJ Should add `.replace(/^0+/g, '')` to get rid of leading zero.

Comment: @RoyJ Sorry to ping you again in this thread. I think this implementation having a flaw. For example if I type in a number in the middle, the caret resets to the end of the input. Apart from that, use [`this.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#:~:text=There%20is%20also%20the%20vm.%24nextTick() "nextTick") might be a good practice.

Comment: @PennyLiu Those are separate issues from the question asked. To solve the cursor position issue, you'd have to note where your cursor is and then put it back. I think I answered such a question at some point. Alternatively, you could use `v-model.lazy` so that it only gets updated when you're done with input.

Comment: @PennyLiu [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479433/392102) is the cursor-position answer. Note that the commas in this problem make it trickier.

Comment: better to use function in `@key.up` of element instead of `watch` in entire page , to prevent unwanted data changing and less cpu usage

Comment: @hadiahadi `watch` doesn't watch a page, it watches a variable. In this case, `price`.

Answer (score 4):

To people who are looking for doing mask for multiple fields then it's kinda pain to use `watch`, so may be we can use [v-money](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-money) (docs included). And check the demo [here](https://vuejs-tips.github.io/v-money/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vuetify, a new light-weight library called '[vuetify-money](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-money)' has been published. Super easy to use for money value inputs, it is **a text field that will add commas as you type.** Here's a [demo.](https://bnm4g.csb.app/)

All properties you use on a v-text-field can also be used, so it is easily customizable.

Step 1

```
npm install vuetify-money --save
```

Step 2

Create a src/plugins/vuetify-money.js file with the following content:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VuetifyMoney from "vuetify-money";
Vue.use(VuetifyMoney);
export default VuetifyMoney;
```

Step 3

Add file to src/main.js :

```
import "./plugins/vuetify-money.js";
```

(main.js is the file where you usually put this)

```
new Vue({render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Step 4
Use it in your code !

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vuetify-money
      v-model="value"
      v-bind:options="options"
    />
    Parent v-model: {{ value }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    value: "1234567.89",
    options: {
      locale: "ja-JP",
      prefix: "$",
      suffix: "",
      length: 10,
      precision: 2
    }
  })
};
</script>
```

You now have a text field that will add commas as you type while keeping the v-model values perfectly fine. It also prevents any non-number inputs so you hardly need front-end validation checks excluding customized cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your method, you can make your `AddCommas` method like this :

```
AddCommas: function(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(",", ".");
}
```

There is a little thing to know about event listener in VueJS. You can access the event object in the handler, but for this, you need either to use this syntax `v-on:keyup="AddCommas"` (no parentheses), or this syntax `v-on:keyup="AddCommas($event)"` (useful when you have multiple parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I used Inputmask with vanilla, for vue 2,  and it works perfectly.
[Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

```
    <script src="../src/assets/js/libs/jquery-inputmask/inputmask.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/assets/js/libs/jquery-nputmask/bindings/inputmask.binding.js">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var selector = document.getElementById("txtOrderQty");
    var im = new Inputmask({ alias: "currency", digits: 0, allowMinus: false }
    im.mask(selector);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label :class="{required:$attrs.required}">{{ label }}</label>
    <input v-model="model" class="form-control" :class="{invalid : error}" type="text" pattern="\d+((\.|,)\d+)?"
           v-bind="$attrs">
    <div v-if="error" class="invalid-tooltip">{{ error[0] }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InputNumber",
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {modelValue: '', error: '', label: ''},
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        // return this.modelValue ? this.modelValue.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") : this.modelValue
        return this.modelValue ? this.modelValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : this.modelValue
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', Number(value.replaceAll(',','')))
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```