# Input cursor jumps to end of input field on input event

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I’m trying to convert the user input to uppercase on input event

so, whenever I type a key in the input field I’m facing the following issues

1. The cursor jumps to end of the input value when user types in the middle.
2. the last typed character (not the last character) is not converting to uppercase.

Here is the link to JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aeL051od/ to reproduce the issue

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      input: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.input = e.target.value ?
        e.target.value.toString().toUpperCase() :
        e.target.value;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="input" @input="handleInput"> {{ input }}
  <!-- {{ input }} is just for reference -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the variables `input` and `event` are for? because it seems the wrong value is being set

Comment: @anurupr `input` is the v-model to store the input value that user enters, and `event` is to store the event emitted on @input

Comment: What's the expected output? As you type each letter, each letter SHOULD be capitalized in the display portion?

Comment: @TejaD so you want the data to be stored as uppercase in `input`? or do you want the original input that the user enters?

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek I'm expecting to get the user entered value in all Caps (UPPERCASE), also when user moves the cursor to somewhere in between the letter and types a character the cursor position should not jump to the end of the input.

Comment: @anurupr Yes, user entered value to be stored in uppercase

Comment: Why dont u try like this `<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="input" @input="handleInput">
  <p>{{input}}</p>
</div>` fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dagalti/umvbfzxp/

Comment: @TejaD just like @dagalti  posted. You're showing the value of `event` variable which has the original data stored

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the "cursor jumping to the end" error?  I tested on Firefox. Are you using another browser?.

Comment: @anurupr yes, I'm using chrome

Comment: Actually it did happen. Ok so the error happens because you are updating the text input with a new value. The cursor will always go to the end. So you shouldn't update the input variable if you want that issue to go away

Comment: @anurupr I understand that, but I tried to set the cursor position using setCursorPosition(), but no luck

Comment: how about using CSS `text-transform: uppercase;`, is there any downside with this approach? here is the fiddle jsfiddle.net/wq1otb0e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you (or Vue) copy a new value into an input, the cursor will be set to the end of the input. If you want to retain the previous position, you will need to capture the position, make the change, then on the `$nextTick` restore the position.

Also note that if you are going to set `this.input` in the handler, there's no point in your using `v-model`, too. It's also unlikely that saving the `event` is sensible, but you can.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      input: null,
      event: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      const el = e.target;
      const sel = el.selectionStart;
      const upperValue = el.value.toUpperCase();

      el.value = this.input = upperValue;
      this.event = e;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        el.setSelectionRange(sel, sel);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @input="handleInput">
  <p>{{ event ? event.target.value : null }}</p>
  <p>
    {{input}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: how about using CSS `text-transform: uppercase;`, is there any downside with this approach? here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wq1otb0e/

Comment: `text-transform: uppercase;` this will not change the data inside `input` variable. You have to convert input data when use on other functions.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious but what is the purpose of `this.event = e;` inside of `handleInput(e)`?

Comment: Only to populate the `event` data item that I use in the display. Just demonstrating that it can be saved and used.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ event ? event.target.value : null }}` here you   display target value.

you have to display converted `input` value. The should be like below

```
 <div id="app">
      <input type="text" v-model="input" @input="handleInput">
      <p>{{ input }}</p>
    </div>
```

for Cursor Jump issue get the position of the cursor on start then after update value set back cursor to start position

```
  handleInput(e) {
          var start = e.target.selectionStart;
            this.input = this.input.toUpperCase()
          this.$nextTick(()=>{
                  e.target.selectionStart = e.target.selectionEnd = start;
                    })
        }
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r53ecug6/

Comment: I've updated the question, but that doesn't solves the issue

Comment: updated the answer with cursor fix issue. updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r53ecug6/

Comment: I still face the same issue with your new fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve your issue but you need to introduce a new variable in the code

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="text" v-model="input" @input="handleInput">
   <p>{{ updated_value }}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data() {
       return {
           input: null,
           updated_value: null
       }
   },
   methods: {
       handleInput(e) {
           this.input = e.target.value;
           this.updated_value = e.target.value ? e.target.value.toString().toUpperCase() 
         : e.target.value;
       }
   }
});
```

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymtvoedb/)

Summary: 
1) Use a new variable (updated_value) to store the uppercase version of the input and use that as the value for `<p>` 
2) This ensures that the input value is not updated , thus not causing the issue of the cursor to jump

Comment: I used the `{{ input }}` just for reference, I think using two variables is not a good idea. what if the same logic has to be implemented on 10-20 fields? show we keep duplicates for each v-model?

Comment: that's a good point. which is why you have to mention that in the question. for what you are asking. there will be some html changes too

Comment: I suggest you update your question. because what you are asking is not matching with the question that you had asked initially. its best to keep answers matching with the question

Comment: yup. but still the original question remains answered.