# How to automatically add comma on amount displayed in input field if the customer clicked a button with specified amount?

Tags: javascript, html

The customer may click a button with specified amount and the amount would display in input field. I'm trying to automatically add a comma on the displayed amount but it's only working if the amount is typed. What would be the easiest way to do it?

```
<input type="number" class="input-char-amo" id="d-total" step="10000" value="0" min='10000' max="5000000" / required>
```

https://codepen.io/Cilissaaa/pen/vYYGjYB

Answer (score 1):

You could use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method. It returns a string with a language-sensitive representation of a number.

```
let n = 1000000;
n.toLocaleString(); //"1,000,000"
```

Answer (score 0):

chek it once. Hope it helps.

I have found the solution on this link: [Can jQuery add commas while user typing numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632359/can-jquery-add-commas-while-user-typing-numbers)

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number">
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually looking for an automatically add comma on the amount that was selected from a specified amount in a button.

Comment: Can you reproduce a fiddle .. it will help to understand better..