# Calculation for comma number gives NaN value

Tags: javascript

I tried to multiply 2 input where user need to key in the number but the output gives me NaN value.
The input number btw have comma separator. I tried to implement the method from the link below and the comma separator is working. It just that when I multiply them it gives me NaN value.

[Can jQuery add commas while user typing numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632359/can-jquery-add-commas-while-user-typing-numbers)

Can anybody help me with this. Really appreciate your help.

Javascript

```
$('.textInput').on('change keyup', function() {

      // skip for arrow keys
      if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

      // format number
      $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
        ;
      });

      product_total_price=0;

      var product_price= Number($('#id_Product-0-price').val());
      var product_quantity= Number($('#id_Product-0-quantity').val());

      product_total_price= product_price * product_quantity;
      $('#id_Product-0-total_price').val(product_total_price);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have modified your inputs to show `commas`, which is totally fine, BUT you didn't remove the `commas` before casting/converting them to `Number`.

A quick test of converting a Number from string `"1,234"` will give you a NaN result. See screenshot:

[image]

Solution:

1. Remove Comma
2. Then cast to `Number`
3. Then compute `product_total_price`

To remove all commas, simpy use:

```
yourString.replace(/,/g, '')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! The calculation is working now but how can I add the comma  separator back to the output ?

Comment: You simply need to run `product_total_price.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')` before assigning it to your output.